# Ruby on Rails after_save error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, save, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am facing Following problem, since i m a newbie to ruby on rails and not also i m not able to understand fully  after_save callbacks, have got stuck

```
    class StoreOpeningStock < ActiveRecord::Base
     after_save :add_stock

     def add_stock
        s = Stock.find_by_product_id(self.product_id)
        if s.product_id?
        s.update_attributes(:product_id => self.product_id, :quantity => self.quantity, :price => self.price)
        else    
        Stock.create(:product_id => self.product_id, :quantity => self.quantity, :price => self.price)
  end
    end
    end
```

i am getting this as error

> undefined method `product_id`

Basically just checking if Stock has a product? if yes.. do update else Create new Stock.. I Feel The problem is with s.product_id...but not sure..Any guidance on this subject would help alot...Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you rin db:migrate? And please provide a desc of the database table :)

Comment: @AbePetrillo- Problem got solved thanks to MurifoX :) but i appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is with this chunk of code:

```
if s.product_id?
```

Problably the **product_id?** method doesn't exist, and problably what you want is something like this:

```
if s
```

This checks if **s** exists in your database from your previous query. If **s** is nil then you create a new record.

Comment: @MurifoX- Thanks alot...silly mistake.. :) Hey Can u recommend any blog or site where i can study callbacks and also get lot of examples??

Comment: Take a look at this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html and this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview . There's not much material about callbacks on the internet, but i believe if you take a good read at this, and try some examples on a sample app, you will learn quite quickly.